# Django: GEOSException on ModelMommy mommy.make function

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests, model-mommy

getting a weird error from Model Mommy when I am trying to create a mommy model

```
GEOSException: Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSWKBReader_readHEX_r".
```

Weird thing is that the only goes stuff is in another function - which is actually successfully used by these other functions to create mommy models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error appear erroneous. It appears it had nothing to do directly GEOS.

Rather I was missing a required field that is a foreign key to a models that has a Point field.

This was giving me an error

```
    dossier = mommy.make('foo.Bar',
                         bar='bar',
                         created=timezone.now())
```

This fixed the problem

```
    dossier = mommy.make('foo.Bar',
                         foo='foo',  # required foreign key field
                         bar='bar',
                         created=timezone.now())
```